# Getting a node after write/read from gml NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I'm having a problem while getting nodes after reading a GML graph. (I'm sorry I can't provide you with a exact reproducable code, because my code is 500 lines long, and smaller reproducable examples are giving weirdly correct results). So I'll try to describe it as well as I can:

I've created a moderately large graph G (40k nodes, 1 mln edges). I can access its nodes by its String labels by simply executing `G['something']`. I've written it into the GML file, and then read it. Now: I can't access the nodes by its labels like before (I'm getting `KeyError`), but I can access them by ids (that were created during writing the GML file, Am I right?) i.e. `G[1]` gives me an AtlasView:

```
AtlasView({0: {'weight': 1}, 3253: {'weight': 8}, 9694: {'weight': 1}....
```

But 0, 3253, 9694 are also ids, not labels. Do you know what went wrong?

Here's my write and read code:

```
G = nx.Graph()
for mp in mps:
    G.add_node(mp.name, bipartite=0)
    for word in mp.speeches:
        G.add_node(word, bipartite=1)
        if not G.has_edge(mp.name, word):
            G.add_edge(mp.name, word, weight = 1)
        else:
            G[mp.name][word]['weight'] += 1
#Here I can simply acces the node by G[mp.name]
# and the output is i.e. {'wznawiać': {'weight': 2}, 'obrady':....
nx.write_gml(G, "test.gml")

G = nx.read_gml('test.gml')
#Here I can't acces the node by G[mp.name], but only by it's id
```

Also, when I'm trying to reproduce problem on a smaller example I'm getting correct results. Maybe it's something with encoding?

Comment: Cn you clarify what you expected `G[1]` to be?  The output you got means that node `1` has a neighbor `0` and the associated edge has weight `1`, another neighbor `3253` whose associated edge has weight `8`, etc.

Comment: Rereading this a bit more I think my confusion in understanding may be in figuring out what you mean by `id` versus `label`.  Is your concern just that writing and reading is causing the node name to shift from being a string to an integer?

Comment: Yes, exactly - before I could refer to the nodes by a String (Which I refer to as Label) and after I can only acces the node by an int (which was automaticly generated, so it's useless for me)

Comment: The output of
>>>>'Some_String_That_Is_Definitely_In_Graph' in G 
>>>>True
But after the write/read is:
>>>> 'Some_String_That_Was_Definitely_In_Graph' in G 
>>>> False
>>>> 'Id_of_node_with_this_String' in G
>>>> True

Comment: Also: when I'm using exact same code, but I provide less data, everything works just fine

Comment: Can you look at test.gml for smaller graphs as well as for this one?  Does that give any hints?

Comment: Smaller graphs gives correct results. I think the problem is rather in reading than writing - I've checked the file manually - all is there, and in correct way, the same way as in smaller graphs. It's just that bigger, when read, gets corrupted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather a workaroud than a solution but works when you can generate the file again (if you have a solution I'll be happy to see it since I've spend a day on it):

**TL;DR: If you can generate the graph once again, do it and save it in other format.**

**What I've learned:**
Somehow, in my case, when **reading** (the file itself is ok, I've checked it manually in text editor) larger NetworkX Graph form the .gml file, the graph becomes corrupted - Ids (generated automatically for file) and Labels (by which the nodes can be accessed) are shifted. It looks like this (this code will work. The problem appears only when analyzing larger data graphs):

```
#prepare the data:
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node("String1")
G.add_node("String2")
G.add_edge("String1", "String2", weight = 1)
nx.write_graphml(G, "test.graphml")
nx.write_gml(G, "test.gml")

#now reading:
gml = nx.read_gml('test.gml')
graphml = nx.read_graphml('test.graphml')

#let's sort the edges by weight just to make this example clearer:
seGml = sorted(gml.edges(data=True),key= lambda x: x[2]['weight'],reverse=True)
seGraph = sorted(graphml.edges(data=True),key= lambda x: x[2]['weight'],reverse=True)
print(seGml[0])
print(seGraph[0])
```

gives output:

```
(0,1, {'weight': 1})
('String1', 'String2', {'weight': 1})
```

In the gml case it's impossible to get the nodes by G["String1"] (gives KeyError) and getting all the attributes into the dictionary sometimes gives the ability to reach the node label i.e.: `dictOfAtts[0]` gives `'String1'`, but sometimes it also gives the Key error

**How to workaroud it:** If you can generate the graph once again, do it, and write it in other format (.graphml worked for me). BUT you can't just read the .gml, then write it to .graphml and once again read the .graphml - it's still corrupted.